# Keep Flash Mobile StageWebView and HttpService cookies in sync - Android

Tags: android, flash, cookies, httpservice, stagewebviewbridge

In a Flash Builder mobile app, I use a StageWebView and a HttpService to communicate with an ASP.NET web application.  Initially, the user logs into the web app in the StageWebView, then later I do REST like communication to the ASP.NET web app using Flash HttpService.   The problem is that the REST calls using HttpService are not recognized as an authenticated user.  They are redirected to the logon page since the user is not authenticated.  This is an issue on the Android, it works on the Ipad.

The ASP.NET is using Forms authentication, so I believe that the authentication values are kept in a cookie.  The cookies aren't shared in in the Android StageWebView and HttpService, they are different web sessions.  Is there a way to grab the cookies from the StageWebView and place them in the HttpService so that it's calls will also appear to be the same authenticated user.

If not, are there some other alternative solutions to this problem?